# The build failed because the "/deep/" in my scss

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

When i try to build my project, the angular accuse this error:

/deep/ nb-card.popover-card {
^
Expected selector.
╷
400 │ /deep/ nb-card.popover-card{
│ ^
╵

I cant change this because is a project from my enterprise. This error happens just in my Macbook Air M1, the build happens normally in Windows and the npm install happens normally too.

I verified all the version Node, Angular, node-sass, reinstall the node-module and nothing work.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `/deep/` with `::ng-deep`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.